# How to make first option a default value in dropdown using Jquery-Chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown whose value I need to default to a first value available in the dropdown option.

Js:

```
$('#chosen').find('ul.active').find('li.child') // will return me an array of options.
   [
     <li class="child" data-option-array-index="1">Abs</li>
     <li class="child" data-option-array-index="2">Abg</li>
     <li class="child" data-option-array-index="3">Abk</li>
   ]
```

I tried to default it to the first value by doing:

```
 $('#chosen').find('ul.active').find('li.child').attr('data-option-array-index').prop('selected', true);
```

But this returns an error. I'm not sure how to select a value for default when the dropdown options are a result of array.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you can't add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the first item without javascript?

Comment: That's not a dropdown . . . that's a list.

Comment: Also, if it's a drop down, why are you using `ul` and `li`. Isn't  `<select>` and `<option>` more appropriate?

Comment: @DevinH. its  a dynamically generated list..so the html just has a <select> tag...its the plugin that does the <ul><li>..the html only has a static <select> tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, my guess is that you are using a plugin or library that creates stylized "dropdowns", using HTML lists (i.e., `<ul>` and `<li>` tags), styled with CSS to make it look like a dropdown.

The problem that you are facing is that the `selected` property is specific to the `<select>` element, so trying to add it to an `<li>` is likely why you are seeing an error.

Now, not knowing what plugin/library that you are using, I can tell you that, in order to make sure that the selection made in the "fake" dropdown is still passed to the server when it is submitted, these dropdowns are usually tied to a hidden `<select>` behind-the-scenes, using some form of JavaScript, and there is also usually a method in the API that allows you to manually auto-select the value that you want to.

Assuming that I am right about using an external plugin/library, I'd take a look at the documentation for more information on how to set a default selection.

---

Based on your comment that you are using the jQuery Chosen plugin, and, after looking at the options page on the Chosen website ( http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html ), it looks like you should simply be able to place the `selected` property in the `<option>` value that the plugin is applied to and it will automatically select the value in the generated dropdown.

> selected, disabled - Chosen automatically highlights selected options and disables disabled options.

If you need to add the `selected` property **AFTER** the plugin has been applied, you would use JS/jQuery to add the property to the `<option>` that you want selected and then refresh the Chosen dropdown with this:

```
$('#YOUR_SELECT_ELEMENT').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: the plugin im using the jquery chosen

Comment: Updated the answer, based on the Chosen documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#chosen').find('ul.active').find('li.child')[0].prop('selected', true);
```

You get the first element in the array of options returned. Then you set its property "selected" to true.

Comment: tried already...gives me this: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...)[0].prop is not a function".

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Doing some research, it seems the prop function was implemented in version 1.6+. Maybe try using the .attr function instead of .prop.